# How does Mathematica compute the determinant of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

I have been trying to write efficient code for calculating the matrix determinant for some time now. I noticed last night that Mathematica is able to compute the determinant of a $200 \times 200$ random matrix I made in seconds. My code in python is nowhere even close to this. I looked around but couldn't find much information on how it works, can anyone shed some light on what is going on under the hood?

Specifically, I want the exact determinant value. I tried C++ originally for speed but long long quickly overflows for even order 10 matrices. Python's inbuilt BigInt type seemed preferable.

Comment: `Det[]` uses [Gaussian elimination in the inexact case](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#5783), [row reduction in the exact case](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#1705), and [direct cofactor expansion or Gaussian elimination in the symbolic case](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#19866).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is very interesting. Could you perhaps suggest a method for when the given matrix is symmetric? I looked into Chomsky decomposition, and then [LDLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition_2). This in particular was useful because I don't need to worry about square roots, but the division part requires me to use floats, which causes loss of precision. Increasing precision, while possible in Python, is very costly here.

Comment: *Chomsky* decomposition??  So when did the famous linguist take up linear algebra?  I presume you mean *Cholesky* decomposition.

Comment: And now I am jumbling up my subjects. I think I need sleep. :| Yes, I do mean Cholesky. My bad.

Comment: The answer in a comment by @J.M. is pretty good. That said, I wonder if this is a bit outside the forum scope. For example, I don't see enough of a clear framework even to provide an example. From the wording of post I'm guessing matrices of integers or maybe rationals are the thing of interest, but even that much is not obvious.

Comment: I agree seems off topic, or should be considered answered.  Worth a note though that direct row reduction naturally leads to working with fractions, which mathematica readily handles. If you've been trying to do it with pure integers you might look into the python fractions module. (No clue how that performs..)

Comment: @george2079 In many cases Mathematica will use one-step (Bareiss) reduction which is "fraction free". That is to say, quotients are taken, but they are exact and hece denominators get removed.

Comment: I understand we are going a bit off-topic. I also went off of on a tangent there, but yes, my question is answered. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Daniel, I think you're more qualified to write an answer to this question than I am, tho. :)